# Entity Framework Database First Stored Procedures Passing Null Strings C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

I am working for a client helping them rewrite a legacy application they wrote.  They would like to reuse all of the stored procedures they already created in their legacy application.

I figured importing all of their stored procedures and having Entity Framework do the work creating all of the C# functions would be helpful. I did this with a database-first approach.

After doing so, I realized that they consistently pass nulls to their string columns in the database if they are blank. That is the way they want to treat all of their strings. It seems when I call the C# Entity Framework functions that were created for the procedures it converts them to blank. It seems it also will not let you use `DBNull.Value` either.

I'd hate to have to build all of the stored procedure calls manually. I know and have read that will work, but that seems crazy that Microsoft never thought to allow null strings when calling the EF created functions.

We are using Entity Framework 6.1.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this without manually creating the call to the stored procedures? The numeric values work fine. This is just an issue with strings.

Let me add some code to hopefully better explain.

Here is the entity framework created code:

```html
//ENTITY FRAMEWORK CODE

public virtual ObjectResult<prCUSTOMER_SEARCH_Result> prCUSTOMER_SEARCH(Nullable<int> acc_Num, string cust_Name, string address_line_1, string city, string state, string zipCode, Nullable<int> doc_Number)
        {
            var acc_NumParameter = acc_Num.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("Acc_Num", acc_Num) :
                new ObjectParameter("Acc_Num", typeof(int));
    
            var cust_NameParameter = cust_Name != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Cust_Name", cust_Name) :
                new ObjectParameter("Cust_Name", typeof(string));
    
            var address_line_1Parameter = address_line_1 != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Address_line_1", address_line_1) :
                new ObjectParameter("Address_line_1", typeof(string));
    
            var cityParameter = city != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("City", city) :
                new ObjectParameter("City", typeof(string));
    
            var stateParameter = state != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("State", state) :
                new ObjectParameter("State", typeof(string));
    
            var zipCodeParameter = zipCode != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("ZipCode", zipCode) :
                new ObjectParameter("ZipCode", typeof(string));
    
            var doc_NumberParameter = doc_Number.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("Doc_Number", doc_Number) :
                new ObjectParameter("Doc_Number", typeof(int));
    
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<prCUSTOMER_SEARCH_Result>("prCUSTOMER_SEARCH", acc_NumParameter, cust_NameParameter, address_line_1Parameter, cityParameter, stateParameter, zipCodeParameter, doc_NumberParameter);
        }
```

IF I CALL THIS WITH THESE PARMS:

var recs = context.prCUSTOMER_SEARCH(null, null, null, null, "NJ", null, null);

It doesn't return any records.

If I call this form SQL server:

prCUSTOMER_SEARCH null, null, null, null, "NJ", null, null

It returns data.

Here is the stored proc definition:

```html
ALTER PROCEDURE
 [dbo].[prCUSTOMER_SEARCH]( @Acc_Num integer = null,
     @Cust_Name varchar(50) = null,
     @Address_line_1 varchar(50) = null,
     @City varchar(24) = null,
     @State char(2) = null,
     @ZipCode varchar(10) = null,
     @Doc_Number integer = null)
as
begin
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: The only solution I could come up with would be to modify the stored procedures to and setting the parameters to Null if empty string is passed in.  It seems very disappointing that Microsoft gives you this great ability to create the classes you need to easily execute stored procedures, but they left such a large hole in the tool they created.